# CSS: any way to make overflow force box to grow?

Tags: css

I have a sidebar within a larger page. So I created a div with float:right and width:30%. Inside the div is a pre. Depending on the size of the browser window, the pre may be wider than 30%. So the text flows off the right edge of the sidebar.

overflow lets me say to put on scroll bars. But what I really want to do is let the div grow to fit the width of the pre. But I can't just set the width to auto because there is other text inside the div, and if I make the width auto it will fill the width of the screen rather than being a sidebar.

Is there any way in CSS to set a minimum width but let the box grow to accommodate a pre, a long unbreakable string, etc?

*Update*

Okay, someone asked for the code. Here's a slimmed down example that demonstrates the issue.

```
<html><title>Sidebar Test</title>
<div style="width:50%;float:right;border:1px solid black;">
<p>Here is some text for the sidebar. La di da di da. Here's more text.</p>
<pre>
This is a pre with a fairly long line.
</pre>
</div>
<p>Here's the non-sidebar text. Write a few lines worht of text here. Here we go.
Lorem ipsum whatever.
</p>
</html>
```

Paste that into a file, then shrink the window and you'll see that "this is a pre with a very long line" will extend outside of the sidebar.

Comment: Why don't you start by sharing your code.

Comment: Have you thought about just doing overflow-x:auto; on the pre itself? that way, only the code snippets will be scrollable.

Comment: @natewiley: Okay, possible. Not how I wanted it to look, but better than running off the end of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `display:table`/`inline-table` that will help to shrink/espand the box to its content.

You could as well set a `min-width` instead a width to allow the floatting box to expand.

example with `display:table` added to your snippet

```
#preonboard, #preonboard pre {
  border:dotted;
  display:table;
}
```

demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqrIj

content around `pre`, will make this floatting box grow as well . You could set a max-width for these other content.

Comment: Now this actually worked! I have never used display:table before and I don't know exactly what the rules are about how it works, but it's looking like it could solve a number of layout issues that I've been struggling with, where I knew that I could lay things out the way I want with tables but I was trying to follow the "don't use tables for layout" dogma.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the display of the containing div to `display: inline-block;` then it would grow/shrink according to the width of its child.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and ... it didn't work. Maybe it requires other tagging somewhere to work.